# Visual Studio 2019 Can't Use GPU Usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sharpdx

I'm working on a c# project with the library SharpDX to render objects from binary files. I want to profile the GPU usage since I have problems with the render time and the FPS. For some reason, I can't find the option in the profiler of Visual Studio 2019 Pro. I searched on google, and I can't find anything. Also, I'm using the trial version. Is there a restriction with the trial version?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the 'Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX' component through the Visual Studio Installer:

[image]

Afterwards the profiler tools will include the 'GPU usage' option:

[image]